# Ruby on Rails (5.2.3) error binding address (Errorno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've been doing some Ruby on Rails development on my local machine, and I want to host a Rails app on my own web server, which I set up from scratch. It is running Ubuntu 18.04 and using nginx as a server. I followed the instructions on [this site](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-ruby-on-rails/) to set up Rails on my server and created a test app. This is my config/database.yml file:

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 9.1 and up are supported.

default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development

  username: <my username>
  password: <my password>
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  username: <my username>
  password: <my password>
production:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_production
  username: myapp
  password: <%= ENV['MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

However, when I try and run the rails server, it comes up with the following:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.3 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.6.3-p62), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
        29: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
        28: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        27: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        26: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        25: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        24: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        23: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        22: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        21: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        20: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        19: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        18: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
        17: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        16: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        15: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        14: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
        13: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
        12: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
        11: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:53:in `start'
        10: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:297:in `start'
         9: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:73:in `run'
         8: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:186:in `run'
         7: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/single.rb:98:in `run'
         6: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/runner.rb:153:in `load_and_bind'
         5: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:90:in `parse'
         4: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:90:in `each'
         3: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:106:in `block in parse'
         2: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:273:in `add_tcp_listener'
         1: from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:273:in `new'
/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:273:in `initialize': Cannot assign requested address - bind(2) for "192.168.7.202" port 5432 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
```

I've googled the error but nothing has helped. My IPv6 is turned on (the lines that are supposed to be commented out are). I've tried different local IP addresses and different port numbers (3000, 3001, 5432, 8080) and nothing works.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: as the Puma output says, its running in development mode, not production, so I'm guessing that you don't have puma & nginx configured properly.  I would search for pump and nginx rails server - and follow a tutorial.

Comment: Also note that in the tutorial you linked there is a typo about the db port 5432 in the testing environment (see the comments at the end of the tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to bind to an address is not an address on your machine.  Ie. if you run `ifconfig | grep "inet "` you won't see that `192.168.7.202` address?

What's your `config/puma.rb` look like?

Comment: I ran the ifconfig command and you're right, the address wasn't listed (it's using 10. IP addresses rather than 192.168 addresses).

I bound the server to the address listed, which was the local IP of the server, and it worked. However, I couldn't see the site when I navigated to the address. I am accessing the server through SSH, but the computer I'm using is on the same network as the server. Not sure what's going on here.

Comment: Here is my config/puma.rb file:

threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
threads threads_count, threads_count
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }
plugin :tmp_restart

Comment: Also, I tried binding to another address on the 10.0.0 subnet, but got the same error message. Now I get the same error message when binding to the original address.

Comment: It's impossible to do this sort of thing in comments.  You said that my suggestion solved *this* problem (ie, your server now starts).  So, mark this as Accepted answer, and then create a new question with the new problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and I think issue has to do with having both 127.0.0.0 and ::1 pointing to localhost on /etc/hosts. I downgraded to Puma 3.4.0 and it resolved the issue.

Comment: Here is my /etc/hosts file:  
127.0.0.1       localhost  
10.0.0.250      coruscant  

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts  
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback  
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes  
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

Answer (score 0):

`Cannot assign requested address - bind(2) for "192.168.7.202" port 5432 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL`

To me it looks as if puma tries to bind to the port that is configured as database (postgresql) port.

On a typical Linux system you can use `netstat -tlpn` to see which processes (web server, ssh daemon, ...) are bound to which IP adress (`0.0.0.0`means **all**, `127.0.0.1` is what can usually be referred to as **localhost**) and ports (22: typically sshd, 3000: typically rails dev server, 5432: usually postgresql).

How do you start puma? How does the configuration look like?

```
$ rails server --help                                                                          Usage:
  rails server [puma, thin etc] [options]

Options:
  -p, [--port=port]                        # Runs Rails on the specified port - defaults to 3000.
  -b, [--binding=IP]                       # Binds Rails to the specified IP - defaults to 'localhost' in development and '0.0.0.0' in other environments'.
```

You could try to start it like `rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000`.
But be careful with this, as this opens the development server to be accessible at port 3000 also from all other computers in the network (`0.0.0.0`). If you see that this works, switch to `127.0.0.1`.